# Cant open .xls files in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a '.xls' file and when i try open it, the Excel seems that will open (show the start Screen) and suddenly it closes.

My Excel version is 2010.

tks.

Comment: Does it happen only on that one `xls` file, or on any that you try to open? (And welcome to StackOverflow!)

Comment: It does on any that I try.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

Just modify the parameters(RegisterKey) in:

**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ Applications \ EXCEL.exe \ shell \ edit \ command**

The Office update but 'forgot' to delete the old references.
The old references pointed to **Office12**, or 2007 instead of **Office14**, or 2010.

Hope this helps.